# Получить массив из отдельного класса

Tags: java, android

Нужно передать массив `List` из отдельного класса на `IntentService`, который позволяет в фоновом режиме проверять на наличие новых фотографий в сервере.

Использую `VKApi` для вывода фотографий. И сделал такой метод в классе `SearchPhotos`:

```
 public static List<SearchPhotosModel> getPhotosService(Long date)
{
    VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
    params . put(VKApiConst.DATE_START, date);

    final List<SearchPhotosModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("photos.search", params);
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("items");

                if(array.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    Log.d("PollServiceRESPONSE", object.toString());

                    SearchPhotosModel mod = new SearchPhotosModel();
                    mod.setOwner_id(object.getInt("owner_id"));
                    mod.setDate(object.getInt("date"));
                    items.add(mod);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG + "-ERROR", e.getMessage() + " ERO : " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            super.onError(error);
            Log.d(TAG, "ERror Vk: " + error.errorMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
            super.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
            Log.i(TAG, progressType + " - " + bytesLoaded + " - " + bytesTotal);
        }
    }); 
return items; 
}
```

А в классе `IntentService` пытаюсь получить `List` массив таким образом

```
List<SearchPhotosModel> mModel;

//Дата в формате Unix - это просто числа для проверки
mModel = SearchPhotos.getPhotosService(13255235213L);
```

Как можно передать этот массив?

Comment: Скажите еще раз, что, откуда и куда нужно передать?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что приведённый вами код не возвращает в переменную mModel нужные вам значения, сервис прекращает работу, а вы не понимаете почему?

Comment: Из метода getPhotosService через Return на другой класс не передается. Мне нужно в IntentService проверить дату вывода последней фотки из ВК, если есть еще новые оповестить пользователя об этом. И чтобы это сделать мне нужно чтобы эта функция выводила мне эту дату, но по какой-то причине из Метода onComplete() массив через Return не передается. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил(

Comment: ИЗ этого метода getPhotosService() Нужно передать List массив в новый класс IntentService.

getPhotosService этот метод находится в классе SearhPhotos